# Is there something wrong with this proof question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Question: If $P(x)$ is a predicate using a variable x and $Q$ is a statement that does not contain x, show that $$((\exists x.P(x))\implies Q) \iff (\forall x.(P(x)\implies Q))$$

Does this question make sense? I don't even know where to start because it seems to imply that there is a contradiction by itself: the first statement is that there is only one $x$ but the second statement is that there are all $x$. How can both of this be simultaneously true at the same time? Unless we assume there is only one $x$...which I don't think is what the question gives.

Also, what kind of concepts should we use here? The most obvious one I could see is that by taking out the $\exists$ symbol, it becomes a $\forall$ symbol. But I have never seen this concept before. Could the question be set wrongly?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the operator $\exists$; it doesn't mean there is *only* one $x$, but rather that there is *at least* one $x$. And this is indeed a true equivalence.

Comment: This actually makes perfect sense if you think about it.  The first statement says "if any human being has six toes, then frogs can dance".  The second says "for every human being, if s/he has six toes, then frogs can dance".  Think about it.  For everybody, if s/he has six toes, then *someone* has six toes so if 1 is true, 2 is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A universal can be seen as a kind of conjunction over all objects over the domain. That is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of a universal like this:

$\forall x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...$

I use $\approx$ since this is technically *not* a logical equivalence, but if you really want to prove the above equivalence, you'd need to go into formal semantics, and that might be a bit to much to ask for a beginner in logic. But, what you would be doing there *does* follow this basic idea, so let's just leave it more informal.

OK, so now:

$$(\exists x \ P(x)) \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\neg (\exists x \ P(x)) \lor Q \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$$

$$(\forall x \ \neg P(x)) \lor Q \approx$$

$$(\neg P(a) \land \neg P(b) \land \neg P(c) \land ...) \lor Q \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$(\neg P(a) \lor Q) \land (\neg P(b) \lor Q) \land (\neg P(c) \lor Q) \land ... \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$(P(a) \rightarrow Q) \land (P(b) \rightarrow Q) \land (P(c) \rightarrow Q) \land ... \approx$$

$$\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q) $$

Comment: That's a very nice and formal way of proving the equality..darn great.

Comment: @user102938475 And yet it's considered neither a proper formal proof nor a proper semantical proof, as I really mix up the two. But yes, it works very nicely.

Answer (score 4):

The quantifier $\exists x$ does not mean "only one $x.$" It means "for at least one $x.$"

But there is also another difference in the way the quantifiers are used: one applies only to $P(x)$ and the other applies to the entire implication $P(x)\implies Q.$
Depending on the truth value of $Q,$ it is possible for $P(x)\implies Q$ to be true even though $P(x)$ is false.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. But interpreting the question in such a way, "for at least one x" still seems to be in conflict with "for all x". How can I resolve this contradiction?

Comment: It's true that $\exists$ is not the same quantifier as $\forall,$ even when it is correctly described. The hint in the second paragraph has more to do with the solution of the problem.

Comment: I think I might I have solved it. I used a truth table and lay out P and Q explicitly, and found that in all cases the implication is true for both ways.

Comment: @user102938475 i don't think you can enumerate all the values of $P$ in a truth table if $P$ depends on a term $x$

Comment: The last sentence of the answer is an understatement; if $P(x)$ is false then $P(x)\implies Q$ is true, regardless of $Q$.

Comment: @ziggurism You're right about not being able to enumerate all the truth values of $P(x)$ in general. But if the OP works out the case where the underlying set, over which the variable $x$ ranges, has $3$ elements (which is feasible), that should provide a pretty good understanding (though admittedly not a proof) of the general case.

Comment: @AndreasBlass good point. but i hope OP is clear on the distinction between propositional logic and predicate logic.

Comment: " "for at least one x" still seems to be in conflict with "for all x". How can I resolve this contradiction?"  How is that a conflict? "At least one president of the United States was a man" and "every president of the United states was a man" aten't in conflict, are they?